# Filtering array while removing items from other arrays from the same indexes that got removed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to filter an array (testCopy) that need to have the items from other parallel arrays (testCopy2, and testCopy3) removed from the index that gets filtered out. So I am hoping to get something like testCopy [0, 2], testCopy2 [1,3], and testCopy3 [3,5]. So the same items from the indexes that got removed are removed from the other two. I tried slicing them off by passing index from filter but that didn't seem to do the trick, any idea how I could go about doing this?

```js
let test = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5];
let test2 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5];
let test3 = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9];

let testCopy = [...test];
let testCopy2 = [...test2];
let testCopy3 = [...test3];

let testClone = testCopy.filter((item, index) => {
  if (item === 0 || item === 2) {
    return true;
  } else {
    testCopy2.splice(index, 1);
    testCopy3.splice(index, 1);
    return false
  }
});

console.log(testClone, testCopy2, testCopy3); // [0, 2],  [1, 3, 6], [3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: When you splice items from the copies, the indexes no longer match up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to start with `testCopy2` and `testCopy3` filled, you can do it like this:

```js
let test = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5];
let test2 = [1, 2, 3, 6, 5];
let test3 = [3, 4, 5, 8, 9];

let testCopy = [...test];
let testCopy2 = [];
let testCopy3 = [];

let testClone = testCopy.filter((item, index) => {
  if (item === 0 || item === 2) {
    testCopy2.push(test2[index]);
    testCopy3.push(test3[index]);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(testClone, testCopy2, testCopy3);
```

Comment: @ArrayKnight when adding an answer, click the page with `<>` on it - it will let you create a runnable snippet that you can insert into your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could use splice to inject a null and then filter them out. Though means multiple loops.

```
let test = [0,1,2,4,5];
let test2 = [1,2,3,6,5];
let test3 = [3,4,5,8,9];

let testCopy = [...test];
let testCopy2 = [...test2];
let testCopy3 = [...test3];

let testClone = testCopy.filter((item,index)=>{
    if(item === 0 || item === 2) { 
        return true;
    } else { 
        testCopy2.splice(index,1,null);
        testCopy3.splice(index,1,null);
        return false
    }
});

testCopy2 = testCopy2.filter((val) => val !== null)
testCopy3 = testCopy3.filter((val) => val !== null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of items to keep, by using `Array.map()` on the 1st array, and returning `true` or `false` according to the filter condition. Now filter all arrays using the respective index of the `keepItems` array.

```js
const test = [0,1,2,4,5];
const test2 = [1,2,3,6,5];
const test3 = [3,4,5,8,9];

const keepItems = test.map(item => item === 0 || item === 2)
const testCopy = test.filter((_, i) => keepItems[i]);
const testCopy2 = test2.filter((_, i) => keepItems[i]);
const testCopy3 = test3.filter((_, i) => keepItems[i]);

console.log(testCopy, testCopy2, testCopy3); // [0, 2],  [1, 3], [3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

[splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) deletes array elements in-place. When an element is deleted, position of other elements in the array shift. Therefore the indices no longer match on subsequent deletes. That is the reason for unexpected output.

When `splice()` deletes an element, only elements after the deleted element in the array are affected not the ones before it.

So to avoid such index conflicts caused due to in-place deletion, iterate the array in reverse and delete.

```js
let test = [0,1,2,4,5];
let test2 = [1,2,3,6,5];
let test3 = [3,4,5,8,9];

let testCopy = [...test];
let testCopy2 = [...test2];
let testCopy3 = [...test3];

for (let i = testCopy.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if(testCopy[i] !== 0 && testCopy[i] !== 2) { 
    testCopy.splice(i, 1);
    testCopy2.splice(i, 1);
    testCopy3.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(testCopy, testCopy2, testCopy3);
```